# Confusion with timelike geodesics in de Sitter space

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, geodesics, de-sitter-spacetime

Without deriving the whole geodesic, I'm thinking I should be able to qualitatively see how the geodesics will curve just by looking at the connection coefficients.  Given the [static coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_space#Static_coordinates)

$$ds^2 = -(1-\frac{r^2}{\alpha^2})dt^2 + (1-\frac{r^2}{\alpha^2})^{-1}dr^2 + r^2d\Omega^2$$

and the fact that $\Gamma^r_{tt}$ tells us how $e_t$ turns toward the $r$ direction as it self-transports, and the fact [as shown here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_of_the_Schwarzschild_solution#Calculating_the_Christoffel_symbols) that, when $ds^2 = B(r)dt^2 + A(r)dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega^2$,

$$\Gamma^r_{tt} = -\frac{B'}{2A}$$

I plug in and find

$$\Gamma^r_{tt} = -\frac{r}{\alpha^2}(1-\frac{r^2}{\alpha^2})$$

But this is negative when $r \lt \alpha$, meaning $t$-geodesics curve toward the origin.  But we know they should diverge away from each other.  I tried it for the Schwarzchild metric and it works fine -- it's negative outside the horizon meaning they converge toward the black hole.  Why doesn't it seem to work for de Sitter space?